# Can you use mysql workbench to store local wordpress sites on your own host?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost, mysql-workbench, lammps

I have a new pc and I am re-installing my entire dev-area. But I am making a mistake setting up mysql workbench.

So, on my old laptop, I used lamp en phpmyadmin to set-up my localhost to create local wordpresses. The sites get stored in de phpmyadmin mariadb, the wordpress sites go in the htdocs file. You configure the db in phpmyadmin, en the configfile from the wordpress. Next, if you go to localhost/sitename .. I get my local wordpressite.

Since I am a junior java developper, some people said to try to also learn to work with the mysql workbench. I have set up a mysqlserver and mysqlworkbench. Using commandbashes, I can see my connections are working. Also the connection in msql workbenc works. here below a copy of this:

```
muski@MuskiPro:~$ sudo mysql -u root
[sudo] wachtwoord voor muski: 
Sorry, probeer het opnieuw.
[sudo] wachtwoord voor muski: 
Sorry, probeer het opnieuw.
[sudo] wachtwoord voor muski: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
muski@MuskiPro:~$ sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 26
Server version: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> 


muski@MuskiPro:~$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

The next thing I would do using lampp was putting a new blanc wordpress in htdocs, make the config.php file and then being able to set up the wordpress by going to my localhost in the webbrowser.

This is not possible. Because, lamp is not installed, so I have no htdocs file. On the other hand, mysql workbench confirms i have a localhost now.

My question is: Is it necessary to install lampp and create a localhost like that or is it possible to set up this procedure using the localhost of mysql workbench? Or maybe it is not possible at all to use mysql workbench for wordpresssite? I am missing something here.

Since I will also use intellij Ultimate to connect to the db's, it is very necessary i set this up correct. But i would prefer to do it without phpmyadmin this time.

Thank you for your feedback.

Kr,

Yannick

Comment: Workbench is a desktop (native) MySQL client program. It doesn't provide a web server. HeidiSQL is another native client program, with a bit less UI cruft than Workbench. phpmyadmin is a web-based MySQL program. It uses a web server but doesn't provide one. [Digital Ocean has a nice walkthrough of rigging WordPress](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-a-lamp-stack) on an ubuntu server. I've used it for desktop setups. You can definitely omit phpmyadmin from your setup.

Comment: @O.Jones, I have read the steps of your link very carefull and thourough. I understand that omiting phpmyadmin means doing this steps straight in the cmd bash, or using another web-based mysql program? Also, I seem to understand that installing phpmyadming on lampp is a different connection than the one IntellijeUltimate and MySQLworkbench use? Cause then I think I am just gonna reinstall phpmyadmin under the lamp server.